# cronometer with javascript and vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I´m doing a cronometer with javascript in vueJS. I need that my time starting for 5 min 300 sec

and after continue counting minutes and seconds... but time start after 5 min.

my cronometer is running, but i can´t do that after 300s start to count minutes

```
// Declaro variables para después de los 5 minutos.
        let sec= 0, min = 0, hour = 0;

// Para contar hasta los 5 minutos
    let startMin = 5*60, cronometro = 0;
cronometro = setInterval(function (){
                        if(cronometro >= startMin){
                            sec++;
                            if(sec == 60){
                                min++;
                                sec = 0;
                                if(min == 60){
                                    hour++;
                                    min = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        minutos.innerHTML = min
                    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve this:

```
cronometro = setInterval(function (){

                    contadorSegundos = sec++;

                    if(contadorSegundos == 300){
                        sec = 0;
                        minutos.innerHTML = 5;

                        if(sec == 60){
                            min++;
                            minutos.innerHTML = min;
                        }
                    }

                    

                    console.log(contadorSegundos);

                }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You store seconds in a variable referring to minutes. I suggest renaming it.

If you add a check inside the minute-increment condition where you divide the startMin by 60 you have the trigger you where looking for.

```
if(sec == 60){
  min++;
  if (minute == startMin/60) {
    // do whatever you want to do after the time has passed
  }
  sec = 0;
  ...
}
```